# How to push Object element to an array in Vuejs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a small application in `VueJs`,
Following is my data set:

```
data(){
    return {
        pusher: '',
        channel:'',
        notify: [],
        notifications: '',
        notificationsNumber: '',
    }
},
```

where I'm having an axios call in created property of components as:

```
axios.get('api/notifications', {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        this.notify = response.data.notifications
        this.notificationsNumber = this.notify.length
    }
}).catch(errors => {
    console.log(errors);
})
```

I'm having `pusherJs` implemented, so I'm having following code:

```
this.pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxx', {
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});

var that = this
this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe('stellar_task');
this.channel.bind('company_info', function(data) {
    console.log(data.notification);
    that.notifications = data.notification
});
```

Once the value is being obtained from pusher I want to push this to my array notify as watch property, something like this:

```
watch: {
    notifications(newValue) {
        this.notify.push(newValue)
        this.notificationsNumber = this.notificationsNumber + 1
    }
}
```

So the problem is the data format which I'm receiving through pusher is in object form and push function is not getting implemented in this:

**Screenshot:**

[image: Console log of pusher response]

Help me out with this.

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.notify)` inside the `watch`? If it's an `array`, it must have `push`.

Comment: @morgh is right, `this.notify` doesn't look to be an array.

Comment: @MatWaligora I've already defined it as an array in data set, By the way I don't know what happend but while doing console.log I'm getting the answer.

Comment: @morgh I did console.log and it is working. Even I removed console.log() it is working now, may be some watch function error during loading the component. Now it is coming perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption that `response.data.notifications` is an *Array Like Object*.

So all you have to do is:

```
this.notify = [...response.data.notifications];
```